# Lightning compatiblity with bootstrap

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bootstrap

I am facing a different issue as when I use bootstrap css.Here is my code:

```
<ul id="insideScroller" class="scrollable-menu scrollbar list-group" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" >

   <aura:iteration var="sobj" items="{!v.SobjectRecords}">

     <!-- Navigation to record detail page works only SF1-->
     <li class="list-group-item" id="{!sobj.SId}" onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" >

       <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!0 lt v.fieldsToDisplayCount}">
         {!v.lstFldDisp[0]} : {!sobj.f1}<br/>
       </aura:renderIf>

       <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!1 lt v.fieldsToDisplayCount}">
         {!v.lstFldDisp[1]}  : {!sobj.f2}<br/>
       </aura:renderIf>

       <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!2 lt v.fieldsToDisplayCount}">
         {!v.lstFldDisp[2]} : {!sobj.f3}<br/>
       </aura:renderIf>

     </li>
   </aura:iteration>
 </ul>
```

I am able to see the scrollbar in SF1 and the desktop.But when I load the same page in mobile the scrollbar disappears.

Any workarounds over this?

Comment: I met similar issue about scrolling on mobile native Salesforce1. It seems that css styled scrolling is not working on mobile native Salesforce1 . Ultimately I have to use a scrolling library from Salesforce [ScrollerJS](http://scrollerjs.com)

Comment: There is a preventDefault call that disables native scroll events in the Salesforce1 mobile app, unfortunately. I know the product teams are looking at ways to remove this pain, but that's just how it is today. I have not worked on a work-around, so just leaving this as a comment as someone else might have a real solution to the problem.

Comment: Then what should be a proper alternative for it ?I want some workarounds as I have to display around 1000 records in mobile.I thought scrollbar will be a good option to it.I want some suggestions from your end which will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Standard HTML "overflow:scroll" doesn't work in Lightning components.

You can create a scrollDiv around your div in component and set the following in your css to make it work.

```
 .THIS div.scrollDiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```